# Python: Remove words from a given string

Tags: python

I'm quite new to programming (and this is my first post to stackoverflow) however am finding this problem quite difficult. I am supposed to remove a given string in this case (WUB) and replace it with a space. For example: `song_decoder(WUBWUBAWUBWUBWUBBWUBC)` would give the output: `A B C`. From other questions on this forums I was able to establish that I need to replace "WUB" and to remove whitespace use a split/join. Here is my code:

```
def song_decoder(song):
     song.replace("WUB", " ")
     return " ".join(song.split())
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong with this as I the error of `WUB should be replaced by 1 space: 'AWUBBWUBC' should equal 'A B C'` after running the code. Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is your issue in it ?

Comment: Each time I execute the program it returns the original string not the appended one. It must be a syntax error on my end, however I am not sure where it's going wrong.

Comment: Can original string have spaces in it? If yes what should happen to them after replacing WUTs? What if WUT and space are adjacent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close! [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) does not work "in-place"; it returns a new string that has had the requested replacement performed on it.

> **Return a copy of the string** with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Do this instead:

```
def song_decoder(song):
     song = song.replace("WUB", " ")
     return " ".join(song.split())
```

For example:

```
In [14]: song_decoder("BWUBWUBFF")
Out[14]: 'B FF'
```

Comment: aha! That makes perfect sense. Thanks alot for you help, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable in Python. So changing a string (like you try to do with the "replace" function) does not change your variable "song". It rather creates a new string which you immediately throw away by not assigning it to something. You could do

```python
def song_decoder(song):
    result = song.replace("WUB", " ")  # replace "WUB" with " "
    result = result.split()            # split string at whitespaces producing a list
    result = " ".join(result)          # create string by concatenating list elements around " "s
    return result
```

or, to make it shorter (one could also call it less readable) you can

```python
def song_decoder(song):
    return " ".join(song.replace("WUB", " ").split())
```

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning the real source of issue...Strings are immutuable !

Comment: But it's making unnecessary spaces in th output like this `'  A   B C'`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the point you wanted to remove padding space. I'll update my answer to include this

Comment: Ah that did come up in the codeacademy course somewhere, still getting the hang of things. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess we're alle learning all the time. This was actually my first answer ever on stackoverflow so I learned about their wiki syntax ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do the both steps in a single line.

```
def song_decoder(song):
    return ' '.join(song.replace('WUB',' ').split())
```

**Result**

```
In [95]: song_decoder("WUBWUBAWUBWUBWUBBWUBC")
Out[95]: 'A B C'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really good at cutting down code and making it as efficient as possible but i'll try to be more aware.

Comment: It doesn't actually make it more efficient to put it all on one line. But, since `song.replace()` returns a value, this is a good way to do it, as it avoids having an extra temporary variable.

Comment: @adep7 - don't assume that code like this is better, or more efficient. It's harder to read and understand. This is really bad advice - it solves the problem, but makes your code quality worse - an extra temporary variable is rarely a bad thing.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Noted.

Comment: Sorry? So is it better to have my code centred around readability or as short as possible?

Comment: @adep7 - ALWAYS make your code as readable as possible. Many people mistake short code for more readable code, sometimes they're right, sometimes they're wrong

Comment: Ah ok, well noted, from now on i'll make sure to keep code readable. I've been trying my best to keep commenting on code that I write to make it easier to understand as well. Again thanks for your tip.